# How to remove all lines in a file, then rewrite the file in Compact Framework 3.5 c#

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, windows-ce, streamwriter

In the .net framework using a Windows Forms app I can purge a file, then write the data that I want back to into that file.

Here is the code that I use in Windows Forms:

```
var openFile = File.OpenText(fullFileName);
            var fileEmpty = openFile.ReadLine();
            if (fileEmpty != null)
            {
                var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fullFileName).Skip(4); //Will skip the first 4 then rewrite the file
                openFile.Close();//Close the reading of the file
                File.WriteAllLines(fullFileName, lines); //Reopen the file to write the lines
                openFile.Close();//Close the rewriting of the file
            }
            openFile.Close();
            openFile.Dispose();
```

I am trying to do the same thing the compact framework. I can keep the lines that I want, and then delete all the lines in the file. However I am not able to rewrite the file.

Here is my compact framework code:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

                using (var sr = new StreamReader(fullFileName))
                {
                    // read the first 4 lines but do nothing with them; basically, skip them
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)

                        sr.ReadLine();

                    string line1;

                    while ((line1 = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine(line1);
                    }
                }
                string allines = sb.ToString();

                openFile.Close();//Close the reading of the file
                openFile.Dispose();

                //Reopen the file to write the lines
                var writer = new StreamWriter(fullFileName, false); //Don't append!
                foreach (char line2 in allines)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(line2);
                }
                openFile.Close();//Close the rewriting of the file
            }
            openFile.Close();
            openFile.Dispose();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not able to"? What happens? (You should also use `using` statements for your writer... and it's not clear why you're closing it three times. It doesn't help that your code isn't formatted, nor have you shown where `openFile` is first opened...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
foreach (char line2 in allines)
{
    writer.WriteLine(line2);
}
```

is writing out the *characters* of the original file, *each on a separate line*.

Remember, `allines` is a single string that happens to have Environment.NewLine between the original strings of the file.

What you probably intend to do is simply

```
writer.WriteLine(allines);
```

**UPDATE**

You are closing openFile a number of times (you should only do this once), but you are not flushing or closing your writer.

Try

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fullFileName, false)) //Don't append!
{
    writer.WriteLine(allines);
}
```

to ensure the writer is disposed and therefore flushed.

Comment: I tried that, and I still get the same result. It removed all the data from the file but once it hits 'writer.WriteLine(allines);' it doesn't write the data back to the file.

Comment: Do you get an exception when attempting to write back?

Comment: I really don't like use 'using' but it is the only thing that seems to work right in the compact database. That updated code worked thank you for the help!

Comment: `I really don't like use 'using'` - The `using` statement will help you write more compact, more correct code.  There are no downsides to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to do this to have something like a "rotating" buffer for a log file consider that most Windows CE devices uses flash as storage media and your approach will generate a full re-write of the whole file (whole - 4 lines) every time. If this happens quite often (every few seconds) this may wear our the flash, reaching its maximum number of erase cycles quickly (quickly may mean a few weeks or months).
An alternative approach would be rename the old log file when it has reached the maximum size (deleting any existing file with the same name) and create a new one.
In this was you logging info would be split on two files but you'll always append to the existing files, limiting the number of writes you perform. Also renaming or deleting a file aren't heavy operations from the point of view of a flash file system.